# multiple bar in horizontal bar chart in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, bar

I am trying to show a performance comparison of the different machine learning models by multiple bars in a horizontal bar chart in latex. I have tried the following code:

```
\begin{figure*}[!tbp]
       \centering

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
LSTM,60,10,30
GRU,20,55,22
SVM,35,25,40
NB,35,25,40
}\data

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
create col/expr={
    \thisrow{1} + \thisrow{2} + \thisrow{3} + \thisrow{4}
}
]{sum}{\data}

\pgfplotsset{
percentage plot/.style={
    point meta=explicit,
every node near coord/.append style={
    align=center,
    text width=0.5cm
},
    nodes near coords={
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
    \ifnum\iszero=0
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\ \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
    \fi},
nodes near coords align=vertical,
    yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0},
visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
},
percentage series/.style={
    table/y expr=\thisrow{#1},table/meta=#1
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis on top,
width=10cm,
ylabel=Responses in Percent,
xlabel=Scenario,
percentage plot,
ybar=0pt,
bar width=0.75cm,
enlarge x limits=0.25,
symbolic x coords={LSTM, GRU, SVM, NB},
xtick=data
]
\addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=2] {\data};
\addplot table [percentage series=3] {\data}
\addplot table [percentage series=4] {\data};
\legend{Stylometric Feature, Word Embedding Feature, TF-IDF Feature}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Effect of Epoch in Accuracy and Loss}
  \label{fig:bar_chart_performance_compare}
\end{figure*}
```

But by the above code, I am getting the following picture:

[image]

How to searate the multiple bar in the boave chart? Please help me.

Comment: You can play with `ybar` and `bar width`

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: For example `ybar=0.05cm, bar width=0.35cm`

Comment: Can you give the full code as answer?

Comment: Can you edit your question and give an error-free MWE first, please?

Comment: When you post a question, please always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  X,  Y1, Y2, Y3
LSTM, 60, 10, 30
GRU,  20, 55, 22
SVM,  35, 25, 40
NB,   35, 25, 40
    }\mydata
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=75mm, width=100mm,
%
        bar width=0.22,
        ybar=2pt,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        ytick distance=20,
        yticklabel style={font=\small},
        yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
        ylabel={Responses in Percent},
        xlabel={Scenario},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\mydata}{X},
%
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={font=\tiny,
                                 /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            precision=1,
                                            zerofill,
                                 },
        legend style={legend pos=north east,
                      cells={anchor=west},
                      font=\footnotesize,
                      }
    ]
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex,y=Y1]{\mydata};
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex,y=Y2]{\mydata};
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex,y=Y3]{\mydata};
\legend{Stylometric Feature, Word Embedding Feature, TF-IDF Feature}    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Since I got lost in your percentage code, I omitted this part of your MWE, and left it to you to add it.

[image]